# Setting range error in VBA 2

Tags: vba, excel, range

In below code , these 3 sentences logically is the same (just different form )

the first sentence is okay .the second and third is invalid .

The final purpose is that i want to use the third line (suit my whole program)

!remark :  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("button").Cells(2, 3) =29

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("button")
Set RUArng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RUA").Range("D3:E21")' it is vaild 

'Set RUArng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RUA").Range(Cells(4, 3), Cells(21, 5))'object definition error

   'Set RUArng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RUA").Range(Cells(3, (.Cells(2, 3) - 28) * 2 + 2), Cells(21, (.Cells(2, 3) - 28) * 2 + 3)) ''object definition error
End with
```

## UPDATE

on the last set , it is try to do (29-28)*2+2=4  & (29-28)*2+3=5

if it is not enough to spot out the error , i m willing to show the full code .

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the last `Set`? your subtracting, multiplying and adding????

Comment: @DragonSamu  (29-28)*2+2  & (29-28)*2+3

Comment: So you know the exact value, does it ever change? If not then just put in the exact value instead of calculating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cells passed as a parameter to a Range object must be qualified to reference the same worksheet as the Range object.

`Set RUArng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RUA").Range(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RUA").Cells(3, (.Cells(2, 3) - 28) * 2 + 2), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RUA").Cells(21, (.Cells(2, 3) - 28) * 2 + 3))`

But I'd prefer this:

```
Sub Example()

    Dim wsRUA As Worksheet
    Dim colNumber As Integer, column1 As Integer, column2 As Integer

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("button")
        colNumber = .Cells(2, 3) - 28
        column1 = (colNumber * 2 + 2)
        column2 = (colNumber - 28) * 2 + 3
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RUA")

        Set RUArng = .Range(.Cells(3, column1), .Cells(21, column2))

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the resulting column numbers do exist from your formula...would it be possible to specify ur full path?

wb.ws.range/cells

and try again?

```
Set RUArng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RUA").Range(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RUA").Cells(3, (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("button").Cells(2, 3) - 28) * 2 + 2), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RUA").Cells(21, (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("button").Cells(2, 3) - 28) * 2 + 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is referring to cells D3:E21 on sheet RUA.

```
Set RUArng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RUA").Range("D3:E21")' it is vaild
```

This line is referring to cells C4:E21 on a sheet (which may not be "RUA") and trying to find a range on sheet "RUA" that includes those cells.

```
Set RUArng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RUA").Range(Cells(4, 3), Cells(21, 5))'object definition error
```

Assuming this line is within a `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("button")` blockm this line is referring to cells D3:E21 on a sheet (which may not be "RUA") and trying to find a range on sheet "RUA" that includes those cells.

```
Set RUArng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RUA").Range(Cells(3, (.Cells(2, 3) - 28) * 2 + 2), Cells(21, (.Cells(2, 3) - 28) * 2 + 3)) ''object definition error
```

If you want to use the last format, and don't want to change the With block, I would suggest you create a Worksheet object pointing to sheet "RUA"

```
Dim wsRUA as Worksheet
Set wsRUA = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RUA")
```

and then use that in the following line

```
Set RUArng = wsRUA.Range(wsRUA.Cells(3, (.Cells(2, 3) - 28) * 2 + 2), wsRUA.Cells(21, (.Cells(2, 3) - 28) * 2 + 3))
```